# How to download all folders of folders and files from Share point using python script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file, sharepoint, directory-structure

I have seen many questions and answers in stackoverflow regarding sharepoint topics, but my requirement is quite different

I need to download all folders of folders and files from in that folders, but this type requirement haven't found

so i'm attaching how my folder structure looks like
[image]

in General folder i have other folder so like that i have remaining folders also looks like that
i tried many scripts but didn't useful much
here is site link

**https://abchome.sharepoint.com/sites/QualityGSharepoint/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx**

can anyone please advice how can i proceed, it would be very helpful to mee

FYI
I tried many of examples from stackoverfolw but no one is showed example for multiple folders of folder and files at  time download/access
here i'm attaching some links  i tried many but pasting some links FYI
[Accessing Microsoft Sharepoint files and data using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979467/accessing-microsoft-sharepoint-files-and-data-using-python)

[How to solve directory path problem recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528737/how-to-solve-directory-path-problem-recursively-in-pytho)

https://github.com/iamlu-coding

https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy/issues/5

Comment: I will use sharepoint client library https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/

Comment: If what you are looking for is for one-time-only, then i would suggest using onedrive in order to download all of the document library.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/984110/surjit-samra, Thanks for you're reply i tried many ways using that import statement but no one has questioned or answered for multiple folders at a time, can you suggest me

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8894067/jimas13, Thanks for you're response, I'm very new to the python and Sharepoint onedrive work, can you please elaborate in detail and i tried many ways no one explained about multiple folders at a time

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/839338/dan-dev, I believe you may have some idea can you please see the question and please help me out, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need use some python global functional cases
To get all folders at a time

Comment: Can you please elaborate? This answer is unclear.